# How can I do a CSS3 shimmer animation to an HTML target object?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, effects, keyframe

In a web page, is there a way to do a CSS3 shimmer animation on a target object, like a `DIV`, `A` tag, or `BUTTON`, using keyframes? I'm more concerned with current browsers, not ones older than the release of IE11.

A shimmer animation puts a shining bar at an angle across the object and moves it in a particular direction. It's useful in drawing attention to something on the page. This is great for landing pages in online advertising in order to draw the customer into clicking to purchase.

In this case, the HTML target object would appear as it normally does when the page loads. But, after a few seconds, it moves in from the left in the hidden space outside the visible overflow boundary of the element where you wish to apply this effect, and goes to the right until it is overflowing the HTML target object boundary and off boundary, only to have a delay and appear again. It can be either on top the target object, although the kind of animation I'm looking for is in the background of the target object and shines bright white. While traveling on the target object background, it should be rapid such that it lasts for like 1 second or 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a diagonal gradient background and slide it from extreme far left to extreme far right on a keyframes timer. Add the following to your CSS file and then add the "shimmer" class to your HTML element. I played with the animation speed using a combination of larger numbers on the `background-position-x` property in the keyframe, as well as the animation speed (currently 8s) in the `animation` property of the CSS class.

```
@keyframes shimmerBackground {
    0% {background-position:-5000px 0}
    100% {background-position:5000px 0}
}

.shimmer
{
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(60%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0.85) 60%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position:-5000px 0;
animation: shimmerBackground 8s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: A suggestion is to use more steps in the keyframes. Doing so would give you the ability to both change speed and color on each step/iteration